# Java syntax question: <O> O accept(ObjectVisitorEx<O> visitor)

Tags: c#, java, generics, syntax, translation

Naive question about Java syntax. What does

```
<T> T accept(ObjectVisitorEx<T> visitor);
```

mean? What would be the C# equivalent?

Comment: Isn't that an 'O' ( oh )  rather and a '0' ( zero ) ?

Comment: It's an 'O" (oh), but it does look like a zero.

Comment: O probably isn't the best identifier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# equivalent would be more or less the same.  If the visitor were an interface it would be

```
O Accept(IObjectVisitorEx<O> visitor);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to declare O somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

In C# it could be:

```
O Accept<O>(ObjectVisitorEx<O> visitor);
```

Comment: what's the difference between adding Accept<O> and just Accept as the accepted answer?

Comment: With @AgileJon's answer the class is generic. This way only the method is generic...

Comment: The original question does indeed ask about a generic method.

Comment: (The difference would be more obvious if the two versions were put together (for instance by accepting this answer).)

Answer (score 1):

This is used for passing types as parameters. C# syntax is the same (<Type>). Suggest googling for term 'generics' as this is the term you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.jprl.com/Blog/archive/development/2007/Aug-31.html) a good comparison between Java and C# generics.

Answer (score 0):

see Java: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html
and C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx
A similar C# method could be

```
public T Foo<T>(Queue<T> v) // Queue<T> chosen for simplicity
{
  return v.Dequeue();
}
```